# Ejb refrences another ejb

Tags: ejb-3.0, java-ee-5

I have two EJBs , EJB A references EJB B, both are deployed to the same server.

Each time I try to deploy EJB A it tries to register EJB B which is already deployed and registered which causes error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

Any idea how to prevent EJB A from registering the referenced EJB?

I am using NetBeans and JBoss 4.2.3 as well as EJB 3.0.

Comment: Could you provide more of the stack trace ?

Comment: 10:58:31,359 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem creating service jboss.j2ee:module=mobichannel-txplugin-1.0.jar,uid=426285,service=EJB3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container jboss.j2ee:jar=mobichannel-txplugin-1.0.jar,name=TrxPlugin,service=EJB3,VMID=99b9a8c1e00ae44b:55066fa4:12a79b098fb:-7ffd + is already registered
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Registry.register(Ejb3Registry.java:114)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:494)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.Ejb3Deployment.deployElement(Ejb3Deployment.java:442)
        at

Comment: Did you solve this problem meanwhile? It seems as if I could have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552929/how-should-i-try-to-fix-java-lang-illegalstateexception-in-jboss-is-already-regi

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven build 
you can use

```
<scope> provided </scope>
```

in the pom file of maven of EJB A

Answer (score -2):

Although I cannot imagine why you get an exception if your EJB A is singleton try the annotation [@DependsOn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipvi.html) on A to specify a dependency on B.

Comment: Singletons were introduced in EJB 3.1.