# How should I try to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException in JBoss "is already registered"?

Tags: jboss, ejb, ear, illegalstateexception

I have a web application. When I try to deploy it via Netbeans, the JBoss server throws the following error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///path/to/my/Application.ear" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container jboss.j2ee:ear=Application.ear,jar=Application-ejb.jar,name=Another,service=EJB3,VMID=583c10bfdbd326ba:71d035f1:132a4c6a8ba:-7ffd + is already registered

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.checkComplete(MainDeployerPlugin.java:82) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.checkComplete(ProfileControllerContext.java:138) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.actions.DeploymentStartAction.doPrepare(DeploymentStartAction.java:104) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:101) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:168) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234) [:6.0.0.Final]
```

I found many results when I google this, so this kind of error seems to appear quite often. But all results I saw were posts in forums which didn't show how to fix it in a general way.

The problem seems to be that the application is already registered in JBoss. Where can I get a list of registered JBoss applications? How can I de-register an application (if this could help).

What is a good way to try to fix this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are chances that you may have multiple class files deployed in your .jar directory/archive one of which is places all by mistake. If you have deployed in exploded from on unix you may search the class file by below command for above raised issue as:

```
find . -name Another -print
```

there after remove the unrequired file and restart the server and the above problem should have been solved/fixed/resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Delete** Application.ear from this path:   /path/to/my/Application.ear and then **DELETE** 
EAR from "jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy" because you might have EAR in JBOSS.
**DELETE**  log,data,temp,work folder in jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default.

If you are using eclipse then remove the EAR from JBOSS server and clean the server.
Start the server wihtout EAR and after server gets started directly add EAR without stoping the server and let it publish itself.